# Firebase Dynamic Link on getInitialLink in iOS (using Flutter)

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I have the following code in my application:

For creating the dynamic link I have:

```
/// Function that creates a DynamicLink for a [SingleFashionItem] using [FirebaseDynamicLinks]
  static Future<String> createFashionItemLink(
    BuildContext context,
    SingleFashionItem fashionItem,
  ) async {
    // Get the package information, this function won't probably fail,
    // therefore don't any errors
    final PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: CUSTOM_DOMAIN,
      link: Uri.parse(
          "$CUSTOM_DOMAIN/item?parentID=${fashionItem.parentID}&objectID=${fashionItem.objectID}"),
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        packageName: packageInfo.packageName,
      ),
      iosParameters: IosParameters(
          bundleId: packageInfo.packageName,
          appStoreId: "123456789" // TODO change this AppStoreID
          ),
      socialMetaTagParameters: SocialMetaTagParameters(
        title:
            "${AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("check_out")} ${fashionItem.name}",
        description: fashionItem.description,
        imageUrl: Uri.parse(fashionItem.images[0].url),
      ),
    );

    // Build a short link
    return parameters
        .buildShortLink()
        .then((shortDynamicLink) => shortDynamicLink.shortUrl.toString())
        .catchError((error) {
      print("The error is: ${error.toString()}");

      return null;
    });
  }

// Function that handles the Dynamic Link using [FirebaseDynamicLinks]
  static void handleDynamicLink(BuildContext context) async {
    // Get the initial dynamic link if the app is started using the link
    final PendingDynamicLinkData data =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();

    print("The dynamic data is ${data.toString()}");
    // Handle the dynamic link
    _handleDynamicLink(context, data);

    // Handle when the application is brought to the foreground when being in background
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData data) async {
      _handleDynamicLink(context, data);
    }, onError: (OnLinkErrorException error) async {
      // Send the error to Crashlytics
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.reportNonFatalError(
        exception: error,
        customMessage: "Error while handling the dynamic link: ${data.link}",
        userID: "not-available",
      );
    });
```

And for handling the dynamic link:

```
/// Function that handles the incoming [PendingDynamicLinkData]'s deep link
  static void _handleDynamicLink(
      BuildContext context, PendingDynamicLinkData data) {
    final Uri deepLink = data?.link;
    print("The deep link is: ${deepLink.toString()}");

    // Check that the deep link is null or not
    if (deepLink != null) {
      // Handle deepLink
      var isItem = deepLink.pathSegments.contains("item");

      // Check if the items path segment is contained inside the path segment
      if (isItem) {
        // The deep link contains the items path segment
        final objectID = deepLink.queryParameters["objectID"];
        final parentID = deepLink.queryParameters["parentID"];

        // Check that the itemID string is not null
        if (objectID != null && parentID != null)
          _goToDetailedFashionItemScreen(
            context,
            selectedFashionItemID: objectID,
            parentID: parentID,
          );
      }
    }
  }
```

-> I've added in my

- **Associated Domains** applinks:example.com
- URL schemes com.example.application
- In the **Info.plist**

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
    <array>
      <string>https://example.com/item</string>
    </array>
```

What I'm getting in a null value from the:
`final Uri deepLink = data?.link`
From what I've seen in this Github issue it might be because of a race condition, however this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution that worked for me.
You should use the package "app_links" besides "firebase_dynamic_links".
Here is my code that worked for IOS:

```
       static Future<void>  initDynamicLinkIOS(BuildContext context) async {
        final appLinks = AppLinks();
        final Uri? uri = await appLinks.getInitialAppLink();
        if (uri != null) {
          final PendingDynamicLinkData? data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getDynamicLink(uri);
          Uri?  deepLink = data?.link;
          if (deepLink != null) {
           // do your logic here, like navigation to a specific screen
          }
        }
      }
```